# Calculate the derivative of $\sqrt{1+\cot^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+\cot^2(x)}$$

How to calculate the derivative $f'(x)$? I've been looking at similar problems in my book and at examples, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding it still. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this in a way that would help not just answer this but other questions like it.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
1+\cot^2x=\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin^2x} + \frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}\\
=\frac{1}{\sin^2x}
$$
So $f(x) =1/\sqrt{\sin^2x} =1/|\sin x|$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: You have to treat both cases, since sin can be either negative or positive. So on ]0, pi[ and ]pi, 2*pi[, sin being respectively positive and negative.

Comment: The edit made my last comment useless, forget it

Comment: Yes I know, but my computer does't put in screen, I've been having trouble with my connexion. I'll do it as soon as I get this fixed..

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = \sqrt{x}, h(x) = 1 + x^2, k(x) = \cot x$.
Then $f(x) = g(h(k(x)))$ and $\frac {df}{dx} = \frac{dg}{dh} \frac{dh}{dk} \frac{dk}{dx}$.
$$\frac{dg}{dh} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{h(k(x))}}$$
$$\frac{dh}{dk} = 2k(x)$$
$$\frac{dk}{dx} = -\frac{1}{\sin^2x}$$
Can you continue by yourself from here?

Comment: $-1/\sin^2x$ is the derivative of $\cot x$, not $1+\cot^2x$.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, will correct that now.

Comment: OK, good.  I would delete my comment, but for some reason the delete option for comments hasn't been showing up lately.  The edit option and timestamps on comments have also disappeared.  Has anyone else noticed this, or is it just me the site is messing with?

Comment: Not sure but perhaps it's impossible to delete comments with consequent comments after them.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  I've always been able to delete comments before, even after an interchange.  Oddly enough, your last reply *does* have a timestamp, but the earlier ones don't (at least I'm not seeing them).  And lo and behold, I am suddenly able to edit and/or delete this comment, which was also timestamped, but not my earlier comments!

Comment: Hmm, I can see the timestamps for all comments of our conversation here.

Comment: This is strange indeed.  I think it might just be me (and I apologize for all this clutter, but I'm hoping someone might weigh in with an explanation).  Even more oddly, after I edited my last comment (to say that I could do so) and posted it, the edit and delete options disappeared again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17912/discussion-between-andrei-rykhalski-and-barry-cipra).